# jQuery does not find elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, null-pointer

I am trying this tutorial (http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/) and my jQuery does not seem to work correctly.

I've included the files in my aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript" src="/s/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript" src="/s/js/menu.js"></script>
```

the menu.js is quite simple:

```
$(function() {
  var pull    = $('#pull');
    menu    = $('nav ul');
    menuHeight  = menu.height();

  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
  var w = $(window).width();
  if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
    menu.removeAttr('style');
  }
  });     
});
```

And in my page I got, as suggested in the tutorial:

```
<nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web 2.0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>  
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
</nav>
```

My js-debugger tells me that ***var pull*** is null so the js crashes.

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT1: Thanks for the many replies. Unfortunately the issue hasnt been resolved. The debugger found a lot of errors, I fixed them all, still the same problem. I cant upload my page yet, but it will be part of the landing page of www.netboat.com. This site has a lot imports, but everything seems to be fine. I basically just added the snippets to that page, but jquery wont find the controls... Any further suggestions? Maybe some possible conflicts with other included libraries?

SOLVED: For some reason using jQuery instead of $ worked.

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle for this issue ?

Comment: I think this might help you: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: Code is fine, check your JS/JQuery includes

Comment: The code is working fine for me in my jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your example code seems to be fine. Check if you are referring to right directory structure to access `Jquery` and your local `js` file.

```js
$(function() {
  var pull    = $('#pull');
    menu    = $('nav ul');
    menuHeight  = menu.height();

  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
  var w = $(window).width();
  if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
    menu.removeAttr('style');
  }
  });     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web 2.0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>  
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually working on this jsfiddle, so might be something you're missing on your page.

Check that all the js are loading correctly, open devTools and check for console errors.

```js
$(function() {
  var pull = $('#pull');
    menu    = $('nav ul');
    menuHeight  = menu.height();

  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
  var w = $(window).width();
  if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
    menu.removeAttr('style');
  }
  });     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web 2.0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>  
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what's wrong.. Here's the jsfiddle with the menu being closed from the beginning

> html

```
<nav>
<ul class="clearfix">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Web 2.0</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
</nav>
```

> jQuery

```
 $(function() {
   var pull = $('#pull');
   var menu = $('nav ul');
   var menuHeight = menu.height();

     menu.hide();

  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
   });

  $(window).resize(function() {
     var w = $(window).width();
     if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
       menu.removeAttr('style');
     }
   });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ncsspz8m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your js code inside the document ready.
[Plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/38KP7eL905BYzXz62txD?p=preview)

```
$(function() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var pull = $('#pull'),
            menu = $('nav ul'),
            menuHeight = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function() {
            var w = $(window).width();
            if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });

    });

});
```